# How to download html file from database using GRAILS?

Tags: grails, download, httpresponse

I'm trying to implement simple upload/download file to/from DB functionality using GRAILS. Everything seems to work fine except text/html files.

Domain:

```
class Content {
    byte[] file;
    //filesProperties
    String contentType
    String fileName
    Long size

    static constraints = {
        file maxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 20, nullable: true; //20MB
        fileName nullable:true
        size nullable:true
        contentType nullable:true   
    }
}
```

Action:

```
def getFile()
{
    def content = Content.get(params.id)
    response.contentType = content.contentType
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment;filename="+content.fileName)
    response.contentLength= content.size
    response.outputStream << content.file
    response.outputStream.flush()

}
```

After uploading html file, everything seems good on database site. Simple SELECT shows that file is uploaded already.
When I try to download html file I get Page not found (in Chrome net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).
Action getFile() works good for any other content-type.

Does exist any possibility to force download (not displaying it in browsers) html file this way?

BTW: Why displaying it (response.header without "attachment" value in Content-disposition key) does not work too?

Comment: So you got a 404 error, which means when web browser tried to render the file as a web page, actually it does not exist as a static resource. The problem is that a url like **h ttp://www.somesite.com/path/file.html** will not be treated as a file download link.

Comment: My url is: http://localhost:8080/MyApp/content/getFile/6 where 6 is content id. Why html file should be a static resource and for example pdf or txt not?

Comment: This is a request url, but the returned html file as the response will confuse browser, which may expects a html file for each request.

Comment: OK... I think I get what you mean... I conclude that there is no possibility to display and download this kind of file from db. I would have to pack it into .zip or other archive to make it downloadable, right?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe you can change content type to text instead of HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to force the download:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type: application/force-download");
```